# How to use two recyclerView in single activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to implement two RecyclerView with different layout in single activity. The above RecyclerView should scroll vertical and the one below should scroll horizontal. But when I run the app, only either one RecyclerView is displayed. If first view is displayed then it works properly and scrolls vertical, while second RecyclerView is missing. And if second one is displayed then it scrolls vertical when it should do horizontal scroll and the first RecyclerView is missing.

[Here is what i want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhJ55.png) Source: Github,CardView-Recyclerview-Picasso

Here is my layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundLight"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/CategoriesRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/videoRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CategoriesRecyclerView"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Not working, there is do data displayed in both Recyclerviews. They are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may directly use the 2 Recycler Views without NestedScrollView.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/CategoriesRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/videoRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CategoriesRecyclerView"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And in your CategoriesRecyclerView whose height is wrap_content, use `setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)` on the Layout manager used for the recyler view.

Comment: I am having CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll the horizontal scrollview full upside on page scroll then use scrollview otherwise you can do without scrollview. Also to achieve your layout just give the horizontal recyclerview fixed height and then you can see both recyclerview .

Comment: I am having CollapsingToolbarLayout. And i have tried adding fixed height, but nothing works. Both the layout is using same recyclerview, I think. In debug, second recyclerview is showing null.